# Find web page(s) that links to a specific page in Google Search

Tags: google-search

I got an article from some page, I don't know which. Is there some Google search way of finding the parent page?

Say for example from page A I navigated to page B. Page B is a PDF document. How to instruct Google search to search for pages that link to page B?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: The `link:` search operator support was removed.

[image]

Note: JohnMu is a Googler.

---

The Google Search operator for searching web pages is `link:`. In other words `link:docs.google.com`.

---

**References**
[Search operators - Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any more and is no longer documented.

Answer (score -1):

Just put your (part of it) text in **`" "`** like:

```
"I got an article from some page, I don't know which. Is there some Google 
 search way of finding the parent page?"
```

and search for it:

**[google.com/#q="I got an article from some page, I don't know which. Is there some Google search way of finding the parent page?"](https://www.google.com/#q=%22I%20got%20an%20article%20from%20some%20page,%20I%20don't%20know%20which.%20Is%20there%20some%20Google%20search%20way%20of%20finding%20the%20parent%20page?%22)**